# Postgres: Filter aggregate groups by value of non-aggregate column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Say I have an event table with two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE evt
(
    ts INT,
    evt INT,
    CONSTRAINT pk_evt PRIMARY KEY (ts, evt)
);
```

The first column represents a timestamp and the second column an event id. I want a query to return a set of `ts` such that the corresponding `evt` conforms to an arbitrary boolean expression. For example, return the set of all `ts` such that there exists corresponding events with ids 5 and 6 but not 10. For another example, all `ts` with ids (2 and 3) or (2 and 4) or (2 and 5).

Is there a way to write such a query so that the boolean expression is contained in a single filter clause, perhaps using window functions? Or, is it necessary to parse the expression and then construct the query with joins and unions?

Postgres 11

Comment: `first column represents a timestamp`, why is there `ts INT`, an INT is something different than a timestamp.

Comment: also '{' en '}' in an SQL statement?

Comment: also the name of the `constraint_name` is missing... (see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html )

Comment: @Luuk, fixed. Yes, integers can represent times, in this case milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
with abc as (
  select * 
  from evt 
) 
select * 
from abc 
where exists(select 1 from abc where evt=5)
  and exists(select 1 from abc where evt=6);
  and not exists(select 1 from abc where evt=10);
```

second example:

```
with abc as (
  select * 
  from evt 
) 
select * 
from abc 
where (exists(select 1 from abc where evt=2) and exists(select 1 from abc where evt=3))
   or (exists(select 1 from abc where evt=2) and exists(select 1 from abc where evt=4))
   or (exists(select 1 from abc where evt=2) and exists(select 1 from abc where evt=5))
;
```

Edit after extra info on event:

```
with abc as )
select 
   ts,
   SUM(case when evt=1 then 1 else 0 end) as evt1,
   SUM(case when evt=2 then 1 else 0 end) as evt2,
   SUM(case when evt=3 then 1 else 0 end) as evt3,
   SUM(case when evt=4 then 1 else 0 end) as evt4,
   SUM(case when evt=5 then 1 else 0 end) as evt5,
   SUM(case when evt=6 then 1 else 0 end) as evt6,
   SUM(case when evt=7 then 1 else 0 end) as evt7,
   SUM(case when evt=8 then 1 else 0 end) as evt8,
   SUM(case when evt=9 then 1 else 0 end) as evt9,
   SUM(case when evt=10 then 1 else 0 end) as evt10
   GROUP BY ts
)
select *
from abc
where evt5<>0 and evt6<>0 and evt10=0
```

Comment: I'm looking for `ts` values for which all of the `evt` criteria apply. I think this query returns all `ts` if some `ts` meet each criteria.

Comment: how can one `ts` match `with ids 5 and 6 but not 10` ? This can only be true if they happened on EXACT the same time?

Comment: multiple rows with same ts value.

Comment: luuk, forget that they are timestamps and think of them as indexes or whatever. You may have the same index for multiple events.